# Im creating a program that finds the longest word in a sentence that a user will input. I think i am on the right track

Tags: function

import sys
import string

input("enter some words and i will find the longest")

def longest_element(p):

```
max_len = 0
elem = None
for e in p:
    if len(e) > max_len:
        elem = e
        max_len = len(e)
return elem
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: when i put it into python 3.3 i am not getting anything in return. It asks me to input words but there it doesnt return the longest word. what am i missing

Comment: Well, despite the horrible lack of proper indentation, it would appear that you are 1) inputting something but not saving it anywhere, and 2) defining a function but never calling it...